# How to export variable from react component?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using Mantine for a search bar and I need to get the wordcount of the text area. This is using Nodejs and React. I need to be able to export this value to use in a different file.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, createStyles } from '@mantine/core';
var count = document.getElementById('count');

const useStyles = createStyles((theme, { floating }: { floating: boolean }) => ({
  root: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
  label: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
    top: 7,
    left: theme.spacing.sm,
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    color: floating
      ? theme.colorScheme === 'dark'
        ? theme.white
        : theme.black
      : theme.colorScheme === 'dark'
      ? theme.colors.dark[3]
      : theme.colors.gray[5],
    transition: 'transform 150ms ease, color 150ms ease, font-size 150ms ease',
    transform: floating ? `translate(-${theme.spacing.sm}px, -28px)` : 'none',
    fontSize: floating ? theme.fontSizes.xs : theme.fontSizes.sm,
    fontWeight: floating ? 500 : 400,
  },
  required: {
    transition: 'opacity 150ms ease',
    opacity: floating ? 1 : 0,
  },
  input: {
    '&::placeholder': {
      transition: 'color 150ms ease',
      color: !floating ? 'transparent' : undefined,
    },
  },
}
)
);
export function FloatingLabelInput() {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const { classes } = useStyles({ floating: value.trim().length !== 0 || focused });
  const uniqueid = "input";
  return(
    <TextInput
      id={ uniqueid }
      placeholder="Add anything you want to the book of the internet."
      required
      classNames={classes}
      value={value}
      onChange={(event) => setValue(event.currentTarget.value)}
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
      mt="md"
      onKeyUp={(e) => {
        var text = value.split(' ');
        var wordcount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if (text[i] !== ' ') {
            wordcount++;
            }
          }
          count.innerText = wordcount;
        }
        }
      autoComplete="nope"
    />
      );
}
```

As you can see, it correctly outputs it into html, but returning inside the function doesnt work at all.

I tried exporting it, I tried returning it to the function but it doesn't see it. I tried exporting and using modules exports but that doesnt work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which function are you trying to export? And how are you trying to import it elsewhere?

Comment: As I can see you want to use "wordcount" across multiple components, one way to do this is in the browser local storage, or make your own singleton storage.

Comment: @ГеоргиКръстев I dont want to use localstorage due to security as this will be used. This wordcount is not allowed to be edited in any way.

Comment: @Shawn I am trying to export the onKeyUp function inside the react component. I am trying to import it using the esnext syntax as react uses into my index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code snippet, my root component (called App) is responsible for keeping the app state, but it can give any piece of state to any of its children. It can also give state modifiers (`setX` functions) to its children, which is what I am demonstrating here:

```js
function Input ({ setWordCount }) {
  function updateWordCount (event) {
    setWordCount(event.target.value.split(' ').length)
  }
  return <input type="text" onKeyUp={updateWordCount} />
}

function SomeOtherComponent ({ count }) {
  return (
    <span>: {count} words</span>
  )
}

function App () {
  const [wordCount, setWordCount] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <p>
      <Input setWordCount={setWordCount} />
      <SomeOtherComponent count={wordCount} />
     </p>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.5/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.5/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

As you can see, the `Input` component can call the `setWordCount` function provided by its parent to change a piece of state. Then, the parent (App) can give that piece of state to any number of its children. Each component can live in a separate file too, this would still work…

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but hopefully, this can give you ideas you can reuse in your own code?